# Problem with WordPress Ajax form

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, jquery

I am trying to save data from a form to user meta using ajax, however I am unsuccesful.

I am pretty new to jQuery, and am not sure where I am going wrong, as there don't seem to be any suntax errors.

Here is my code in my plugin file:

```
/**
     * Action hooks
     */
        // Register and Enqueue plugin styles and scripts
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','load_css_and_js');
        function load_css_and_js() {
            wp_register_style( 'krv-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/custom-setts.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style('krv-style');
            wp_register_script( 'krv-script', plugins_url( 'js/custom-setts.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), null, false );
            wp_enqueue_script('krv-script');
            wp_localize_script( 'krv-script', 'krv_obj', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'check_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('krv-nonce') ) );
        }

        function aj_save_setts_settings( $user_id ) {
            check_ajax_referer( 'krv-nonce', 'security' );
            $krv_user_setts = $_POST['user_setts']; 

            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
            update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_setts', $krv_user_setts );
        }

        //Hook Function into WP_Ajax for Admin and Frontend
        add_action('wp_ajax_aj_save_setts_settings', 'aj_save_setts_settings');
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_aj_save_setts_settings', 'aj_save_setts_settings');

        //Add [setts] Form Shortcode
        add_shortcode( 'setts', 'add_user_setts_shortcode' );
        function add_user_setts_shortcode(){
            ?>
            <!-- Create setts Checkbox Loop -->
            <div class="container">
                <form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
                    <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
                        <!-- (Loop) -->
                        <li><input name="user_setts[]" id="<?php echo $setts->term_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $setts->term_id; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> type="checkbox"/><label for="<?php echo $setts->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $setts->name; ?></label></li>
                    </ul>
                    <input name="myBtn" class="kvo_ajax_submit_button" type="submit" value="Save Settings">
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
?>
```

And this is what I have in `js/custom-setts.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    jQuery('.kvo_ajax_submit_button').click(function(){

        var user_setts = user_setts;
        var str = {
                'action': 'aj_save_setts_settings',
                'security': krv_obj.check_nonce,
                'user_setts': user_setts,
            };
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: krv_obj.ajax_url,
                data: str,
                success: function(data){
                    // Code after ajax success

                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
                }
        });
    });

});
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What info are you getting in the console when you debug?

Comment: Nothing. If I put `console.log(user_setts);` right after `var user_setts = user_setts;` in the ajax file, it outputs "Undefined"

Comment: `var user_setts = user_setts;` doesn’t get the value from anywhere.  (I’m on my phone so can only look at segments of the code at a time, sorry if I missed it.)

Comment: Thanks. When you have a chance, do you mind helping me get the value to ajax properly? I would really appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm off to bed as it's 3:30am and I've got to be up and coding by 7:30am - if you're still stuck or my answer doesn't help at all, I can try and look at it again in the morning.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a lengthy discussion Edegist and I actually sorted this all out.  Here's a couple of the key factors that comprise the solution.

One, we had to loop through all of the selected checkboxes to pass via AJAX.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.kvo_ajax_submit_button' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var user_categories = $( 'input[name="user_categories\\[\\]"]' ).map( function() {
            if( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                return $( this ).val();
            }
        } ).get();
        var str = {
            'action': 'aj_save_category_settings',
            'security': krv_obj.check_nonce,
            'user_categories': user_categories,
        };
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: krv_obj.ajax_url,
            data: str,
            success: function( data ) {
                // Code after ajax success
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error : function(req, err){
                console.log('Error:' + err);
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
```

The next step was figuring out why it wasn't saving to the user_meta database.  We realized that the AJAX wasn't transmitting a $user_id, so we addressed that.

```
         function aj_save_category_settings( $user_id ) {
          $user_id = get_current_user_id();
            check_ajax_referer( 'krv-nonce', 'security' );
            $krv_user_categories = $_POST['user_categories'];
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_categories', $krv_user_categories, false );
            wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I modified line 1 of the ajax file to `jQuery(document).ready( function($) {` and changed `jQuery.ajax({` to `$.ajax({` and now it is properly logging the values. However WordPress doesn't seem to be saving the data. On the dev Network page `admin-ajax.php` returns a status of "(canceled)", and there is no response.

Comment: Edit: I also noticed that it is outputting all the values in the checkbox array - not just the items that are selected.

Comment: Thanks! The array is now working, but the nonce change generates this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: nonce is not defined`

Comment: I still get a problem with admin-ajax.php: `XHR failed loading: POST ".../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".` Also, I fired the console.log before `var str = {`. If I fire it at `success`, I get nothing. Also, now in the Network tab, admin-ajax.php has a status of 200, but response is still blank.

Comment: Edit: `console.log( user_categories + ' : ' + str );` at success is outputting `22,21,17 : [object Object]` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106169/discussion-between-tony-djukic-and-edegist).